# WPF Selected Item of GridView on Hyperlink Click

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm, radgridview

I have a Telerik `RadGridView` bound to a collection and I'm sending the `SelectedItem` when a hyperlink is clicked in one of the cells. It works but I have to first click elsewhere on the row to set the selected item. This is not ideal and I'm looking to set the `SelectedItem` when the link, or anything for that matter, is clicked.

I've seen how to do this for a `ListView` with `IsSelected` and `ListViewItem` but nothing for Telerik `RadGridView` or a generic `GridView`.

Here's my link:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Padding="3,0">
        <Hyperlink CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
            AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}}"
            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SomeCommand,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
            AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadGridView}}, Mode=OneWay}">
            Click here please
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to set the [`UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I have these two `Style`s that I use to make a click on a child control get reflected in the `ListBoxItem`... you can just change `ListBoxItem` to `ListViewItem` and it should still work. You probably want to apply the first `Style`, but I've included the second in case the first doesn't completely fulfil your requirments:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemSelectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemSemiSelectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is similar to what I've tried but still not quite working. Will ListViewItem as the target type work with the telerik RadGridView?

Comment: They are the containers for standard `GridView`s, so I would imagine that also goes for the `RadGridView`.